# IntelliJ: Refactor package causes Guice class-not-found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, guice

I change the name of a package from `oldName` to `newName` using IntelliJ's refactor tool. This package contains a Guice provider binding. After refactoring, the main class throws a run-time exception:

```
Message: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.oldName.missingClassProvider
```

In my example, I have refactored `oldName` to `newName`. But the exception indicates it is still looking for `missingClassProvider` in the `oldName` package.

It seems like the classpath has been updated since I am able to import `missingClassProvider`. But it seems like there is a Guice data container that is not being updated.

Can someone kindly explain what is causing this behavior? How do I get Guice to recognize the change in package name?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a Guice problem. Guice doesn't store names anywhere. It is a runtime library configured, usually, when the application starts via a module or modules.

My guess is about a corrupted build. Try to clean and rebuild the project. If you are using some kind of build tool (Maven, gradle) find and execute the *clean* goal.

If you are using just IDEA try to rebuild the whole project using *Build > Rebuild project*.

Comment: Finally had a chance to look into this. All the references to old `project.oldName` are located in the .idea/workspace.xml file. I've tried running the Gradle Clean task. I've also tried using IDEA Build > Rebuild. Neither works. I'll try Invalidate Cache / Restart.

Comment: Most of the references to `project.oldName` in workspace.xml seem to be related to the local history. I also noticed the text "project.oldName" does appear in one other place: .gradle/2.2/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin

Comment: What about a full-text search on the whole project, looking for oldName ?

Comment: I deleted the fileSnapshots.bin file. Yes, I did text search from the project root. oldName only appears in .idea/workspace.xml. I am hesitant to just delete since I have many run / debug configurations I don't want to have to recreate.